# Devise with Ruby on Rails - Force user to change password on first login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, passwords

I have a RoR application (Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2.0) running Devise. I have set it up so that admin users (identified the "is_admin" boolean I added to the user model) are able to create new user account, provide them with a generated password and confirmation email. This is all working properly. I have also added the datetime column pass_changed which should be updated when a user changes their password, and then checked against created_at to make sure that the password has changed since the account was created. If the two dates are equal then the user is redirected to the password change form.

I wrote a procedure for checking that the user has changed their password and placed it in my application_controller.rb:

```
def check_changed_pass
@user = current_user
    if @user.pass_changed == @user.created_at #make sure user has changed their password before accessing internal pages
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, alert: "You must change your password before logging in for the first time"
    end
end
```

Then in my internal_controller.rb (used for all internal that require the user to be logged in:

```
before_action :check_changed_pass
```

So far so good, but the problem comes with attempting to update pass_changed at the right time. I have tried various configurations, but I can't find where to put this code so that it triggers when a password is updated, but not every time the user model is updated, which includes every login and logout, when I only want it to trigger if the password gets updated.

If I place "before_save :update_pass_change, only: [:edit, :update]" in my controller it doesn't trigger on a password update, and if I place it in the User model, I have to put the procedure in the model as well and then it won't pick up current_user as its not available in the model. The ideal thing would be if Devise had a hook for after_password_edit similar to the after_database_authentication hook. I had to override Devise's registrations_controller.rb to remove the line

```
prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [ :cancel]
```

So that admin users would be able to add new users. I tried placing update_pass_change there, but it doesn't seem to trigger before_save on a password edit.

In application_controller.rb

```
def update_pass_change # records that the user has changed their password
    unless current_user.pass_changed != current_user.created_at
    current_user.pass_changed = Time.now
    end
end
```

Similar unanswered question: [Ruby on Rails: Devise - password change on first login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121356/ruby-on-rails-devise-password-change-on-first-login)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a callback on your model and check, before save, if the changes includes your password attribute. Something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :check_password_changed

  private
  def check_password_changed
    self.pass_changed = Time.now if changed.include? 'encrypted_password'
  end
end
```

Comment: I did this and its not working for some reason. check_password_changed runs without error but does not update the pass_changed, though the password gets updated properly.

Comment: @HenryD Check if `encrypted_password` is the correct attribute for the user password.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

1. change datatype of `pass_changed` to `boolean` with default value `false`
2. Then in your application_controller.rb

   ```
   before_action :check_pass_changed

   private

   def check_pass_changed
    unless current_user.pass_changed
      redirect_to custome_password_edit_path, alert: "You must change your password before logging in for the first time"
    end
   end
   ```
3. Then Create custom action in ur users_controller to display the password change form and to update.
   eg. 
   To display form : `custome_password_edit`
   To update :
   `update_user_password`
   also dont forget to write above in `routes.rb`
4. after successful change update the value of `pass_changed` to `true`